# Django: A serious issue or is there a way around?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am stuck with a problem from a week and found no solution either in documentation or stackoverflow.

The issue is annotation over multiple models. If we annotate over multiple models the result is not correct. A ticket raised on this is still open, so we cannot annotate over multiple models. Done.

Now i had a different approach to annotate as follow:

```
    inventory_purchase=productmodel.objects.filter(company=request.user.company.entity)
        purchase=inventory_purchase.annotate(purchase=Sum('exproduct__Quantity'))
        sale = inventory_purchase.annotate(sale=Sum('serviceproduct__Quantity'))
        purchase_return = inventory_purchase.annotate(purchase_return=Sum('dnproduct__Quantity'))
        sales_return = inventory_purchase.annotate(sales_return=Sum('cnproduct__Quantity'))
inventory_movement =  sorted(chain(purchase,sale,purchase_return,sales_return))


    return render(request,'account/inventorymovement.html',{'inventory_movement':inventory_movement})
```

What i did is, annotating each model separately.  Now i have correct data as required.
However this has created an issue in template rendering. My template is:

```
{% for invoices in inventory_movement %}
<tr>
<td>{{ invoices.product_name }}</td>
<td>+{{ invoices.purchase|default:0 }} </td>
<td>-{{ invoices.sale|default:0 }}</td>
<td>+{{ invoices.sales_return|default:0 }}</td>
<td>-{{ invoices.purchase_return|default:0 }}</td>
<td>-</td>

</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Result in html is:
[image]

Each product is displayed multiple times. However i want to show product only once and their respective value in column next to them.
Is there any solution?

Comment: if this is html, can't u use javascript to correct the data accordingly??

Comment: If Django can provide data in required format it would be great. Instead of {key, value1} {key, value2} can give as {key, value1, value2} .

Comment: Cannt use JS for it!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown what `inventory_movement` is or how you're building it up. But surely you just need to add the right elements from each annotation:

```
inventory_movement = []
for (p, s, pr, sr) in zip(purchase, sale, purchase_return, sales_return):
    invoices = {}
    invoices['purchase'] = p.purchase
    invoices['sale'] = s.sale
    invoices['purchase_return'] = pr.purchase_return
    invoices['sales_return'] = sr.sales_return
    inventory_movement.append(invoices)
```

Comment: Edited question. Let me try your solution.

Comment: error 'dict' object has no attribute 'purchase'. Sorry for being new to django. But building a big project and stuck in reporting part.